# Moped: get id after inserting

Tags: mongodb, mongoid, moped

When I use mongo-ruby-driver and I insert new document it returns generated '_id':

```
db = MongoClient.new('127.0.0.1', '27017').db('ruby-mongo-examples')
id = db['test'].insert({name: 'example'})

# BSON::ObjectId('54f88b01ab8bae12b2000001')
```

I'm trying to get the '_id' of a document after doing an insertion using Moped:

```
db = Moped::Session.new(['127.0.0.1:27017'])
db.use('ruby-mongo-examples')
id = db['coll'].insert({name: 'example'})

# {"connectionId"=>15, "n"=>0, "syncMillis"=>0, "writtenTo"=>nil, "err"=>nil, "ok"=>1.0}
```

How I get the id using Moped?

**Update:**

I also try use safe mode but it doesn't work:

```
db = Moped::Session.new(['127.0.0.1:27017'])
db.use('ruby-mongo-examples')

db.with(safe: true) do |safe|
  id = safe['coll'].insert({name: 'example'})

  # {"connectionId"=>5, "n"=>0, "syncMillis"=>0, "writtenTo"=>nil, "err"=>nil, "ok"=>1.0}
end
```

Comment: You can get it in the response if you do a [safe insert](http://mongoid.org/en/moped/) or generate it before the insert like `document = { _id: Moped::BSON::ObjectId.new, name: "example" } id =  document[:_id]`

Comment: I found this issue: https://github.com/mongoid/moped/issues/129. It seems that the only way is generte id with BSON::ObjectId.new and use it. Thanks @chridam.

Comment: I think @hamster_ham's answer is more appropriate than mine, your call to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this [**issue**](https://github.com/mongoid/moped/issues/129):

> It would be nice, but unfortunately Mongo doesn't give us anything
>   back when inserting (since it's fire and forget), and when in safe
>   mode it still doesn't give the id back if it generated it on the
>   server. So there really isn't any possible way for us to do this
>   unless it was a core feature in MongoDB.

Your best bet would be to generate the id before inserting the document:

```
document = { _id: Moped::BSON::ObjectId.new, name: "example" } 
id = document[:_id]
```

Comment: hamster_ham's answer is more consistent with how you would expect mongo to work i.e.  insert document get id back in result.

Comment: @ChrisMcCauley I do agree, OP's call to switch the accepted answer though.

Comment: Well said chridam - respect !

Comment: It is a good solution if you don't want  to be waiting for mongo.

Answer (score 15):

After inserting/saving, the returned object will have a property `inserted_id` which is a `BSON::ObjectId`:

```
# I'm using insert_one
result = safe['coll'].insert_one({name: 'example'})   
result.methods.sort        # see list of methods/properties
result.inserted_id
result.inserted_id.to_s    # convert to string
```

Comment: worked for me without the "safe['coll']", just coll.insert_one(...)